# return specific mongodb embedded document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query mongodb document to return a specific document

Suppose I have the below document and I want to search only the specific details of a given room. Say, I want query to return notes for room_num = 210. How do I do it?

I was able to query by db.locations.findOne({"facility.room.room_num" : room_num});
I don't know how to project room only.
Generalizing the question, how do I project only the embedded document specific entries only.

My document looks like this --->

```
{
  _id: Object("xxx"),
  name: "Campus",
  facilities: [
     { name : "Science",
     rooms : [
          {
             room_num: 210,
             notes: "Chemistry Lab 1",
             Dimension: "x*x"
          },{
             room_num: 120,
             notes: "Chemistry Lab 2",
             Dimension: "x*x"
          }
      ]

    },
    { name : "Arts",
     rooms: [
          {
             room_num: 90,
             notes: "Drawing 1",
             Dimension: "x*x"
          },{
             room_num: 100,
             notes: "Drawing 2",
             Dimension: "x*x"
          }
      ]

    }
  ]
```

Comment: what format are you expecting to get?

Comment: I am expection to get this 
{room_num: 210,
notes: "Chemistry Lab 1",
Dimension: "x*x"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an embedded array (one within another) then you can indeed do this with aggregate. You just need to do a "double" unwind operation:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$facilities" },
    { "$unwind": "$facilities.rooms" },
    { "$match": { "facilities.rooms.room_num": 210 } }
])
```

And if you really want it to look like the original document, then take it a little further:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$facilities" },
    { "$unwind": "$facilities.rooms" },
    { "$match": { "facilities.rooms.room_num": 210 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "facName": { "$first": "$facilities.name" },
        "rooms": { "$push": "$facilities.rooms" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "facities": { "$push": {
            "name": "$facName" ,
            "rooms": "$rooms"
        }}
    }}
])
```

So from your data this would be the result:

```js
{
    "_id" : {
            "0" : "x",
            "1" : "x",
            "2" : "x"
    },
    "name" : "Campus",
    "facities" : [
       {
           "name" : "Science",
           "rooms" : [
               {
                   "room_num" : 210,
                   "notes" : "Chemistry Lab 1",
                   "Dimension" : "x*x"
               }
           ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Or finally if all you need is the inner rooms part of the arrays, then just use a **`$project`** statement at the end, as from the first example:

```js
db.campus.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$facilities" },
    { "$unwind": "$facilities.rooms" },
    { "$match": { "facilities.rooms.room_num": 210 } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "room_num": "$facilities.rooms.room_num",
        "notes": "$facilities.rooms.notes",
        "Dimension": "$facilities.rooms.Dimension"
    }}
])
```

With a result like this:

```js
{ "room_num" : 210, "notes" : "Chemistry Lab 1", "Dimension" : "x*x" }
```

And that should clear it up.

Comment: thanx neil. 
I got it working now. than you so much. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: neil how to extract only the facilities.rooms part I mean rooms should not be shown under facilities.
Should I do it in my programming language or js function that outputs only the room part after extracting it from the json, while disabling everything else from the output using $project

Comment: I am getting this
{ "_id" : ObjectId("534ce1af4b39df0e79064b82"), "name" : "Demo Campus", "facilities" : [ { "name" : "Demo Science Hall", "rooms" : [ { "room_num" : 210, "notes" : "Chem Lab", "last_updated" : "Tue Apr 15 2014 13:07:19 GMT+0530 (IST)" } ] } ] }

Comment: @jalatif You can either do your reformatting in code or use the pipeline. See the final edit on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
db.locations.aggregate( 
 { $unwind: "facilities.rooms" },
 { $match: { "facilities.rooms.room_num" : room_num}},
 { $project: { "facilities.rooms.notes" : 1 }}
)
```

Comment: thanks. 
I got this error
aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: field path references must be prefixed with a '$' ('facilities.rooms'",
 "code" : 15982,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: what is the use of project variable here?
Unwind is for extracting the rooms array here. right?

Comment: Sorry error was from my mistake.
I am getting the current result but I am getting the portion of document outside rooms as well. I only want to get the rooms document.

Comment: @Abhinav It's wrong basically. You need to have **two** unwind stages.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). I believe the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operators are what you are looking for.

```
db.rooms.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    facilities: "$facilities.rooms.room_num"
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$facilities"
}, {
  $unwind: "$facilities"
}])
```

and you would get something like:

```
{
  "result" : [
    {
      "facilities" : 210
    },
    {
      "facilities" : 120
    },
    {
      "facilities" : 90
    },
    {
      "facilities" : 100
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: A novel use of $project and double unwinding, but I'm sure it is not what the OP wanted given the comment on the question.

Comment: thanx yaoxing. I am getting this result allright. 
How can I extract the matching room only.
{
             room_num: 90,
             notes: "Drawing 1",
             Dimension: "x*x"
          }

Comment: @Abhinav I already answered the question, which is why I am correcting those who did not.

Comment: @NeilLunn No it's not what he wants. I posted the answer before he answers my comment because I'm sort of hurry into something else. I thought I can at least show him a way so that in case no one else's answering he can probably find the answer himself. However, you guys definitely provided better answers. So just ignore mine.